# Trouble with Vimeo API frogaloop getCurrentTime

Tags: api, vimeo

I am looking to get the current time from a player, I have the video pausing with this

```
$('#add').click(function() {
var player;
player=$f(document.getElementById('vimeoPlayer'));
player.api('pause');
});
```

but when I try to add

```
player.api('getCurrentTime', function(value) {
alert('yes');
});
```

I get nothing, any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this example I made up will help you understand how the Vimeo API works:
http://labs.funkhausdesign.com/examples/vimeo/froogaloop2-api-basics.html

Comment: Thanks for this Drew, all sorted!